# Worlds Waterways Vector

Tags: vector, vector-tiles

We are trying to export all the world's waterways in vector.

I have imported ERIS as vector tiles on top of the OpenStreet map. I removed all layers that were not waterways but cannot seem to get them out of qgis.

Name
eris
URL
https://basemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/OpenStreetMap_v2/VectorTileServer

Source
serviceType=arcgis&type=xyz&url=https://basemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/OpenStreetMap_v2/VectorTileServer&zmax=19&zmin=0

Provider
vectortile

I am able to export a small section like a town but looking to export the entire world at a scale of 1:27384 to one sheet.

is this possible?

Comment: What's "ERIS"? Do you mean "ESRI"?

Comment: I just tried https://mygeodata.cloud/osm/data/download/ to see how big "all the world's waterways" is going to be as a vector dataset. Britain and Ireland come to about half a million features. The whole world is going to be maybe hundreds of millions. Can you do anything practical with that much?

Comment: You could download the OSM "Planet" file https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm and extract from that, or maybe use one of the services that provide extracts listed on that wiki page. I don't think trying to scrape the whole planet from a vector tiles server source is a good idea. For example, https://data.osmdata.xyz/waterway_EPSG4326.zip which is a 7Gb zip that expands to an 18Gb GeoPackage.

Comment: @Spacedman yes, ESRI sorry!

and i cant know what is practical without being able to try. we are trying to create one large file that can be zoomed in for our local offices. Maybe by continent would be better? hoping to not have to stitch every country.

Comment: we are hoping to achieve some thing like this, with as much information as manageable. 
http://www.fleetmon.net/2013/06/navigable-rivers-map.html

Comment: Yes, and the OSM Planet file has all the waterways for the planet, or the waterways extract I linked has that too, then you can build your own vector tile source or raster tile source or whatever your final output is.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works